# formik nested dynamic object

Tags: reactjs, formik

Could you please advise a solution for the following:

e.g. we have a checkout form with many delivery options, each requires different details, such as:

- in store - requires only `storeId`
- delivery office - requires `cityId` and `officeId`
- courier - requires `address` fields (street, building)

example of state:

```
...,
delivery: {
  type: 'inStore',
  details: { storeId: 1 }
}
```

or

```
...,
delivery: {
  type: 'courier',
  details: {
    address: {
      street: '12 Ave',
      ...,
     }
   }
 }
```

As soon as only one of the above options could be checked I tried to use a radio button component to define a `delivery type`
Also, it is possible to render different components based on `delivery type` (e.g. via switch-case) and fill different `delivery.___` fields.

But if we fill the form for the `inStore` option and then switch to e.g. `courier` option the `storeId` property still is in the state. So how could this switch be properly handled (to left only required properties based on the selected `delivery type`)

Comment: Can we see some code for your handling of the delivery type radio buttons `onChange`?

Comment: currently it works like that: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-8m7o6?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, I've added subform state reset to the radio button `onChange` event handler. So based on a new radio button value (e.g. `deliveryType`) new initial state calculated (e.g. `deliveryDetails`).

Because of this, the new `deliveryType` and the new `initialState` allow rendering related sub-forms without any trouble.

please check the solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-ix0nt?file=/deliveryDetailsForm.js

It is worth mentioning that it is needed to update the subform initial state first, and then updating the dependent variable (e.g. `deliveryType`). So as soon as `values.delivery.details` object is updated **before** the required sub-form rendered the 'controlled-to-uncontrolled' error won't happen.

P.S. current solution uses `switch-case` to decide which `initialState` and which sub-form should be rendered, which is quite a bad design, so if you have any suggestions on how to make it better I would be really glad to hear them.

Answer (score -1):

In your case React try to re-use the same input component for both first `Field` of `store` and `courier` case so it doesn't have to render a complete new node. You can easily fix that by adding an unique `key` prop to each `Field` component:

```
  switch (deliveryType) {
    case "store":
      return (
        <Field
          key={`${name}.storeId`}
          name={`${name}.storeId`}
          value={1}
          placeholder="storeId"
        />
      );
    case "courier":
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Field
            key={`${name}.address.street`}
            name={`${name}.address.street`}
            placeholder="street"
          />
          <Field
            key={`${name}.address.building`}
            name={`${name}.address.building`}
            placeholder="building"
          />
          <Field
            key={`${name}.address.flat`}
            name={`${name}.address.flat`}
            placeholder="flat"
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    case "delivery_office":
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Field
            key={`${name}.cityId`}
            name={`${name}.cityId`}
            placeholder="cityId"
          />
          <Field
            key={`${name}.officeId`}
            name={`${name}.officeId`}
            placeholder="officeId"
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    default:
      return null;
  }
```

[image: Edit Formik Example (forked)]

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is switching from `store` to `courier` doesn't whipe out `storeId`, so the state becomes messy, e.g. : ```{"delivery":{"type":"courier","details":{"storeId":"1","address":{"street":"Ave 12"}}}}```, reproduced here: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-il92i